# Unity Create UI control from script

Tags: c#, toggle, unity-game-engine

I created a toggle by code but it won´t get displayed. 
Furthermore, I can´t change the position of my text field.
I tried a lot and nothing works. This is my current version, maybe you see the mistake.

I´m new to Unity and it is very difficult.

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public GameObject canvas;

    void Start () 
    {
        GameObject newGO = new GameObject("myTextGO");
        newGO.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
        newGO.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        Text myText = newGO.AddComponent<Text>();
        myText.text = "Ta-dah!";
        Font ArialFont =  
           (Font)Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font),"Arial.ttf");
        myText.font = ArialFont;
        myText.material = ArialFont.material;
        myText.color = Color.black;
        myText.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 10, 0);

        GameObject secGO = new GameObject("myGO");
        secGO.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
        Toggle myToggle = secGO.AddComponent<Toggle>();
        myToggle.isOn = true;
        myToggle.transform.position = new Vector3(10, 10, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You are supposed to make the `Toggle` the child of the `Canvas`. You didn't do that in your code. Also, you move a UI component and GameObject with `newGO.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D` not `newGO.transform.position`.

**There are 3 Ways to create a Complete UI Control in Unity:**

**1.Use the [`DefaultControls`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.DefaultControls.html) API to generate it (Easy and Recommended)**

With the `DefaultControls` class, Unity will create the supplied UI then returns the parent of the UI. This is the easiest and recommended way of doing this.
It takes [`DefaultControls.Resources`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.DefaultControls.Resources.html) as parameter so that you can provide the sprites to use when creating the default UI Control.

*Button:*

```
public GameObject canvas;
void Start()
{
    DefaultControls.Resources uiResources = new DefaultControls.Resources();
    //Set the Button Background Image someBgSprite;
    uiResources.standard = someBgSprite;
    GameObject uiButton = DefaultControls.CreateButton(uiResources);
    uiButton.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
}
```

*Toggle:*

```
public GameObject canvas;
void Start()
{
    DefaultControls.Resources uiResources = new DefaultControls.Resources();
    //Set the Toggle Background Image someBgSprite;
    uiResources.background = someBgSprite;
    //Set the Toggle Checkmark Image someCheckmarkSprite;
    uiResources.checkmark = someCheckmarkSprite;
    GameObject uiToggle = DefaultControls.CreateToggle(uiResources);
    uiToggle.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
}
```

*Slider:*

```
public GameObject canvas;
void Start()
{
    DefaultControls.Resources uiResources = new DefaultControls.Resources();
    //Set the Slider Background Image someBgSprite;
    uiResources.background = someBgSprite;
    //Set the Slider Fill Image someFillSprite;
    uiResources.standard = someFillSprite;
    //Set the Slider Knob Image someKnobSprite;
    uiResources.knob = someKnobSprite;
    GameObject uiSlider = DefaultControls.CreateSlider(uiResources);
    uiSlider.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
}
```

*Panel:*

```
public GameObject canvas;
void Start()
{
    DefaultControls.Resources uiResources = new DefaultControls.Resources();
    //Set the Panel Background Image someBgSprite;
    uiResources.background = someBgSprite;
    GameObject uiPanel = DefaultControls.CreatePanel(uiResources);
    uiPanel.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
}
```

*InputField:*

```
public GameObject canvas;
void Start()
{
    DefaultControls.Resources uiResources = new DefaultControls.Resources();
    //Set the InputField Background Image someBgSprite;
    uiResources.inputField = someBgSprite;
    GameObject uiInputField = DefaultControls.CreateInputField(uiResources);
    uiInputField.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
    uiInputField.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().font = (Font)Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf");
}
```

*Dropdown:*

```
public GameObject canvas;
void Start()
{
    DefaultControls.Resources uiResources = new DefaultControls.Resources();
    //Set the Dropdown Background and Handle Image someBgSprite;
    uiResources.standard = someBgSprite;
    //Set the Dropdown Scrollbar Background Image someScrollbarSprite;
    uiResources.background = someScrollbarSprite;
    //Set the Dropdown Image someDropDownSprite;
    uiResources.dropdown = someDropDownSprite;
    //Set the Dropdown Image someCheckmarkSprite;
    uiResources.checkmark = someCheckmarkSprite;
    //Set the Dropdown Viewport Mask Image someMaskSprite;
    uiResources.mask = someMaskSprite;
    GameObject uiDropdown = DefaultControls.CreateDropdown(uiResources);
    uiDropdown.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
}
```

The rest of the UI Controls:

```
public static GameObject CreateImage(Resources resources);
public static GameObject CreateRawImage(Resources resources);
public static GameObject CreateScrollbar(Resources resources);
public static GameObject CreateScrollView(Resources resources);
public static GameObject CreateText(Resources resources);
```

**2.Via prefab and Instantiate**

This method requires that you have the UI already created and saved as a prefab, You can then `Instantiate` the UI when need.

Create a `Toggle` Control from the Editor then save it as a prefab. Delete the original one. You can then `Instantiate` the `Toggle` Control prefab during run-time and position or scale it if necessary.

```
public GameObject canvas;
public GameObject togglePrefab;

void Start()
{
    GameObject uiToggle = Instantiate(togglePrefab) as GameObject;
    uiToggle.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
    //Move to another position?
    uiToggle.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D = new Vector3(...,...,...);
    //Re-scale?
    uiToggle.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(...,...,...);
}
```

**3.Piece by Piece (Hard)**

You do this by first creating a UI from the Editor then study the Hierarchy and components attached to it in the Editor and reproduce it via code.

*GameObject*->*UI*->*Toggle*

For example, this is what Toggle looks like:

[image]

**1**.Create a *Toggle* GameObject then make it child of the *Canvas*.

**2**.Create a *Background* GameObject then make it child of the *Toggle* GameObject.

**3**.Create a *Checkmark* GameObject then make it child of the *Background*  GameObject.

**4**.Create a *Label* GameObject then make it child of the *Toggle* GameObject.

**5**.Now attach components like `Image`, `Text` and `Toggle` to each GameObject like it appears in the Editor.

In Code:

```
public GameObject canvas;

void Start()
{
    makeToggle();
}

void makeToggle()
{
    GameObject toggleObj = createToggleObj(canvas);
    GameObject bgObj = createBackgroundObj(toggleObj);
    GameObject checkMarkObj = createCheckmarkObj(bgObj);
    GameObject labelObj = createLabelObj(toggleObj);
    attachAllComponents(toggleObj, bgObj, checkMarkObj, labelObj);
}

//1.Create a *Toggle* GameObject then make it child of the *Canvas*.
GameObject createToggleObj(GameObject cnvs)
{
    GameObject toggle = new GameObject("Toggle");
    toggle.transform.SetParent(cnvs.transform);
    toggle.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI");
    return toggle;
}

//2.Create a Background GameObject then make it child of the Toggle GameObject.
GameObject createBackgroundObj(GameObject toggle)
{
    GameObject bg = new GameObject("Background");
    bg.transform.SetParent(toggle.transform);
    bg.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI");
    return bg;
}

//3.Create a Checkmark GameObject then make it child of the Background GameObject.
GameObject createCheckmarkObj(GameObject bg)
{
    GameObject chmk = new GameObject("Checkmark");
    chmk.transform.SetParent(bg.transform);
    chmk.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI");
    return chmk;
}

//4.Create a Label GameObject then make it child of the Toggle GameObject.
GameObject createLabelObj(GameObject toggle)
{
    GameObject lbl = new GameObject("Label");
    lbl.transform.SetParent(toggle.transform);
    lbl.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI");
    return lbl;
}

//5.Now attach components like Image, Text and Toggle to each GameObject like it appears in the Editor.
void attachAllComponents(GameObject toggle, GameObject bg, GameObject chmk, GameObject lbl)
{
    //Attach Text to label
    Text txt = lbl.AddComponent<Text>();
    txt.text = "Toggle";
    Font arialFont =
    (Font)Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf");
    txt.font = arialFont;
    txt.lineSpacing = 1;
    txt.color = new Color(50 / 255, 50 / 255, 50 / 255, 255 / 255);
    RectTransform txtRect = txt.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    txtRect.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
    txtRect.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
    //txtRect.y

    //Attach Image Component to the Checkmark
    Image chmkImage = chmk.AddComponent<Image>();
    chmkImage.sprite = (Sprite)AssetDatabase.GetBuiltinExtraResource(typeof(Sprite), "UI/Skin/Checkmark.psd");
    chmkImage.type = Image.Type.Simple;

    //Attach Image Component to the Background
    Image bgImage = bg.AddComponent<Image>();
    bgImage.sprite = (Sprite)AssetDatabase.GetBuiltinExtraResource(typeof(Sprite), "UI/Skin/UISprite.psd");
    bgImage.type = Image.Type.Sliced;
    RectTransform bgRect = txt.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    bgRect.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 1);
    bgRect.anchorMax = new Vector2(0, 1);

    //Attach Toggle Component to the Toggle
    Toggle toggleComponent = toggle.AddComponent<Toggle>();
    toggleComponent.transition = Selectable.Transition.ColorTint;
    toggleComponent.targetGraphic = bgImage;
    toggleComponent.isOn = true;
    toggleComponent.toggleTransition = Toggle.ToggleTransition.Fade;
    toggleComponent.graphic = chmkImage;
    toggle.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Method **#3** is the hardest way to do this so, you should avoid it. Method **#1** Should be fine in this case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great. But the Unity API is still missing basic features - e.g. it will NOT use the default background images, button image, etc (which, by definition, it ought to be doing). But this trick will get past that for you: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-apply-uisprite-image-to-button-and-keep-borders-via-script.386434/#post-2514534

Comment: Yeah. That's one draw back with it. Wish Unity would fix that. Thanks for that link.