# unity show GUILayout.Button under all objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `GUILayout.Area` and I want to add some `GUILayout.Button` into it dynamically(through a script). I also have a side menu button which when the user clicks it, a menu will be shown on top of all objects. I know about sorting layer and second camera but they didn't work and when pressing the side menu button, the `GUILayout.Button` is showing over the menu. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Use Unity's [new UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) for that not this.

Comment: according to what i saied i can't access to unity editor and should write all thing i need via code,so i can't understand how to do this with UI buttons, i'm very new in unity

Comment: You want to create UI Buttons from code? Are you new to C# too or just Unity?

Comment: yes, want to create multiple button from code. i am new to both of them :D

Comment: See Unity's C# [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting). You need that. For creating many UI Controls from script see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194515/unity-create-ui-control-from-script/41219377#41219377).